# List the tab/shp files properties within folders/sub folders w.r.t relative folder path

Tags: ogr, batch

Currently i am using this command line

**For /R "U:\01 My Proj" %f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so "%f" >>U:\New.txt**

to extract all the tab file related information as a text.Instead of giving the path folder...is it possible to run this command w.r.t to the folder wherein which the bat file has been copied ? (Another thing is the sub folders name will have spaces )

What i am trying to do is..save this command as a bat file using notepad & want to run it different folders (like..i'll copy the bat file to the respective folder & execute it).

Will /* in place of Path_folder work ? I've tried that too

Comment: Will it comes under Software_Developmet ?? Since there are tags w.r.t OGR,batch i thought it can be post here. 

Do i have to remove this & post it in stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the /R option. That makes it recursive:

```
For  %%f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so "%%f" >>U:\New.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. But before that, the environment variables should be initiated, rite...I had a tough time to figure this out.

Finally, this code works perfect for me (for both Raster & Vector)

CALL "C:\Program Files\FWTools2.4.7\setfw.bat"
CALL "C:\Program Files\FWTools2.4.7\bin\setfwenv.bat"
For  %%f in ("*.shp",".tab") do ogrinfo -al -so "%%f" >>Vector.txt
For %%f in ("*.tif") do gdalinfo -approx_stats "%%f" >>Raster.txt

Comment: Forget about the FWTools. They are outdated and get no update anymore. Current GDAL builds are available from gisinternals.com/sdk, or from OSGeo4W. If you have QGIS installed, you can use the OSGeo4w Shell as well. These set the Environment as needed by themselves.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Have started to use osGeo4W shell and no worry what so ever about Environment.

But one last question. How to initiate the command within a batch file. I've tried with this one -CALL "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat". But it's not reading the files in the sub folders.