# How to restrict the output parameters in ogrinfo?

Tags: ogrinfo

Just want to know, is it possible to restrict the output parameters while using ogrinfo? For example, I need only the Projection details for a bunch of tab files, that too in a single continuous line and not the other details like Field_name etc. -nocount -nomd -noextent are not working. I find it very difficult to reformat the output csv file.

Currently I'am using this code [List the tab/shp files properties within folders/sub folders w.r.t relative folder path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96186/list-the-tab-shp-files-properties-within-folders-sub-folders-w-r-t-relative-fold) to extract the information

Comment: have you tried `-so`

Comment: yep. It's listing the file name alone

Comment: Is is actually listing a layer name alone. Use -al -so (all layers, summary only). However, it does list the attribute schema that you are not interested in so it is not your command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should rather write that -nocount, -nomd, or -noextent do not do what you would like to achieve than to say that they do not work.

If you are especially interested in projection info you might be satisfied with gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html. Option -o prints projection in all supported formats. One liner you can get with out_type **proj4** or **mapinfo**, but XML might be also good for parsing. Example follows.

```
gdalsrsinfo states.shp -o all

PROJ.4 : '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

OGC WKT (simple) :
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

OGC WKT (no CT) :
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

ESRI WKT :
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

MAPINFO : 'Earth Projection 1, 104'

XML :
<gml:GeographicCRS gml:id="ogrcrs1">
  <gml:srsName>GCS_WGS_1984</gml:srsName>
  <gml:usesEllipsoidalCS>
    <gml:EllipsoidalCS gml:id="ogrcrs2">
      <gml:csName>ellipsoidal</gml:csName>
      <gml:csID>
        <gml:name codeSpace="urn:ogc:def:cs:EPSG::">6402</gml:name>
      </gml:csID>
      <gml:usesAxis>
        <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs3" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG
::9102">
          <gml:name>Geodetic latitude</gml:name>
          <gml:axisID>
            <gml:name codeSpace="urn:ogc:def:axis:EPSG::">9901</gml:name>
          </gml:axisID>
          <gml:axisAbbrev>Lat</gml:axisAbbrev>
          <gml:axisDirection>north</gml:axisDirection>
        </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
      </gml:usesAxis>
      <gml:usesAxis>
        <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs4" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG
::9102">
          <gml:name>Geodetic longitude</gml:name>
          <gml:axisID>
            <gml:name codeSpace="urn:ogc:def:axis:EPSG::">9902</gml:name>
          </gml:axisID>
          <gml:axisAbbrev>Lon</gml:axisAbbrev>
          <gml:axisDirection>east</gml:axisDirection>
        </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
      </gml:usesAxis>
    </gml:EllipsoidalCS>
  </gml:usesEllipsoidalCS>
  <gml:usesGeodeticDatum>
    <gml:GeodeticDatum gml:id="ogrcrs5">
      <gml:datumName>WGS_1984</gml:datumName>
      <gml:usesPrimeMeridian>
        <gml:PrimeMeridian gml:id="ogrcrs6">
          <gml:meridianName>Greenwich</gml:meridianName>
          <gml:greenwichLongitude>
            <gml:angle uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">0</gml:angle>
          </gml:greenwichLongitude>
        </gml:PrimeMeridian>
      </gml:usesPrimeMeridian>
      <gml:usesEllipsoid>
        <gml:Ellipsoid gml:id="ogrcrs7">
          <gml:ellipsoidName>WGS_84</gml:ellipsoidName>
          <gml:semiMajorAxis uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">6378137</gml:semiM
ajorAxis>
          <gml:secondDefiningParameter>
            <gml:inverseFlattening uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9201">298.25722356
3</gml:inverseFlattening>
          </gml:secondDefiningParameter>
        </gml:Ellipsoid>
      </gml:usesEllipsoid>
    </gml:GeodeticDatum>
  </gml:usesGeodeticDatum>
</gml:GeographicCRS>
```

Comment: For some files i've to extract Feature_count also. And the problem with gdalsrsinfo is the layer names were listed in the output.

Comment: At least with GDAL 2.1-dev this command prints only one row and nothing else `gdalsrsinfo test.shp -o proj4`.  But if ogrinfo and/or gdalsrsinfo do  not give the result that you want I believe that the standard answer from GDAL folks would be "Make a Python script".

Comment: We have to extract the details mostly for tab files. That too, very old tab files. That might be the reason i guess

Comment: Similar output for me `gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 test.tab 
'+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'`

Comment: Great. But how to identify the datum with this one ? As you said, have to work around with python script i guess